# Overlay transparent image on hover

Tags: html, css, opacity

I have a `<div>` with a `background-image`. When this is hovered over I would like another image to be placed on top partially transparent so the original image can be seen below.

My current idea involved adding a `:hover` state and changing the above images `display` state to `visible` along with necessary `z-index` values.

Could someone give me an example with jsfiddle.net implementation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whipped up a quick example for you. Hit "Run code snippet" to see it in action.

```css
.image-holder {
  background: url('http://i.imgur.com/5ln9Vmi.jpg');
  height: 500px;
  width: 500px;
  position: relative;
}

.image-holder::before {
  content: '';
  background: url('http://i.imgur.com/khYHDfJ.jpg');
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity .5s;
}

.image-holder:hover::before {
  opacity: .5; /* amount of opacity to blend the two images */
}
```

```html
<div class="image-holder">
</div>
```

Comment: +1 for the before, no additionnal markup. Be aware tho that if your picture is part of your content, make sure to do my method below since background-image are not taken in consideration by screen-reader/crawler for SEO. If it is only for esthetic matter, this one is cleaner tho.

Answer (score 3):

Why not use [opacity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/opacity)?

> The opacity CSS property specifies the transparency of an element, that is, the degree to which the background behind the element is overlaid.
>
> The value applies to the element as a whole, including its contents,
>   even though the value is not inherited by child elements. Thus, an
>   element and its contained children all have the same opacity relative
>   to the element's background, even if the element and its children have
>   different opacities relative to one another.

```
.myTransparentImage{
   opacity: 0;
}

.myTransparentImage:hover{
   opacity: 0.6; /* it's in pourcentage */
}
```

This way, the transparent image, on hover, will appear at 60% `opacity` so you can still see the one below. So it is on top of the other image the whole time but only appears once hovered.

Here is an example in a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/5ob6n7nq/

Answer (score 0):

If I correctly understand you: https://jsfiddle.net/3jabz7d3/

```
<div class="block1">
  <div class="block2"></div>
</div>


.block1 {
  position: relative;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background: url(http://writm.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/08/Cat-hd-wallpapers-1080x675.jpg)  no-repeat center center;
  background-size: cover;
}

.block2 {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: url(http://www.cats.org.uk/uploads/images/pages/photo_latest14.jpg)  no-repeat center center;
  background-size: cover;
  display: none;
  opacity: 0.3;
}

.block1:hover .block2{
  display: block;
}
```